# What does this mean in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, debugging

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>mysqld-nt --defaults-file="D:\MySQL\MySQ
L Server 5.0\my.ini" --standalone --console
100125 10:47:26  InnoDB: Operating system error number 32 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/Operating_System_error_codes.html
InnoDB: File name .\ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Answer (score 1):

The first line starts MySQL. It errors out. Looking up the error message at the URL provided by the error message suggests that:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

I'd guess that MySQL is already running or didn't stop cleanly previously. If you've never seen this before, a reboot would probably help. If it happens a lot, you'll need to figure out why the files are being locked. Some of the [SysInternals tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545046.aspx) can help with that.